# ODE45 speed up and for loops

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, ode

I have a coupled first order ODE to solve of the form

```
dy = f(t, x)
dx = d(f, x)
```

which depend on a common parameter which I have to solve for over some range. I can solve the system using ODE45 and a for loops which increments the parameter of interest at each loop, however, this is very slow. Can I avoid solving this problem in loops? Or what is best practice with problems of this type.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to post a comment but I can't until I get 50 reputation.
What do you need to solve the parameter in each range?
Can't you create a function for solving the parameter and put the function handle in the second argument for ode45?